# Clasic ASP : IIS7 VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7

My company is migrating exising website to Windows server to 2008 R2/IIS 7
from Windows 2003/IIS6.

I was facing error in below statement

```
set obj = Server.CreateObject("MYDLL" )
```

(32 bit file)

So I performed below steps:

1. Register component using the regsvr32 in SysWow64 folder (i.e. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe pathOfTheComponentand)
2. Also register with default in System32 folder:

In Application pool, I then  set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to TRUE.

Now error for above statement is Gone but, error is coming in next line in which method from MYDLL.dll is begin called.

> Error while using object to call method obj.myMethod();

Comment: good sign that you don't have error in ` Server.CreateObject("MYDLL")` -- mean that DLL really registered in system and IIS could access it.

what is inside black-box? what happens inside `MyMethod` function?

Comment: @Zam : This MYDLL.dll is made many years ago... I dont know what it inside MyMethod... I guess from MyMethod some other dll/method file is being called which is not registered... so is it possible to find such dll/method. and

Comment: do you have source code? by using TDUMP.EXE you could list all functions from your DLL, but I suppose something is wrong in DLL code